# Binding a wpf xaml image to System.Windows.Controls.Image is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmapimage

I have an image in wpf application and bind its Source property to System.Windows.Controls.Image in view model but it is not working. But when i bind its Source property to a BitmapImage, it is working. Is there any way to bind Source property as System.Windows.Controls.Image ?

**Xaml Part**

```
  <Image x:Name="ShipMainImage" Source="{Binding MainImageSource}" />
```

**View model Part**

```
 public class StabilityVM : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private System.Windows.Controls.Image mainImageSource;

    public System.Windows.Controls.Image MainImageSource
    {
        get { return mainImageSource; }
        set {
            mainImageSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainImageSource)); }
    }

 protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `System.Windows.Controls.Image` as type of that property. It is a UI element type that is used in a view, but not in a view model.

Declare the property as `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource` - the type of the `Source` property of the Image element:

```
private ImageSource mainImageSource;

public ImageSource MainImageSource
{
    get { return mainImageSource; }
    set
    {
        mainImageSource = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainImageSource));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Clemens for answer. My problem is that why binding of xaml image Source property to System.Windows.Controls.Image is not working. Only binding of Source property to BitmapImage is working. I updated my question please have a look.